# IFrame gets re-rendered all the time in Angular component

Tags: angular, iframe, angular2-changedetection

I have a really strange issue:
I have a super simple component (`ViewerComponent`). There's not much logic in there, only a URL is passed to display a URL (a viewer) in an iFrame. It's HTML looks like this:

```
<iframe class="w-100 h-100 border-0" [src]="viewerUrl | safe: 'resourceUrl'"></iframe>
```

The `safe` pipe is just a DOM Sanitizer.

The problem is, that the iFrame gets constantly re-rendered. It seems it gets re-rendered in every change detection cycle. But, the strange thing is, that the `viewerUrl` is never changed.

Also, the component is not destroyed (I'm checking this in `ngOnDestroy()`, but it does never go there. To make it even more weird, `changeDetection` is set to `OnPush`, and also there's no change registered (checking in `ngOnChanges()`).

It's an Angular 10 application btw. Maybe it is some bug connected to that?

Any help would be very very much appreciated!

@Update:

Please see the safe pipe here:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
            case 'html':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl':
                return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default:
                throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the pipe a pure pipe? could it be that the pipe's change detection is running and is the reason  for reload for iframe?

Comment: What is the pipe doing with the extra parameter?

Comment: Good point with the pipe, I will check it. I will also post its content in my post, give me a min.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was connected to the pipe, because the pipe created a new instance of the object, meaning of that string.

I fixed the problem by injecting the `src` parameter like this:

```
const iframe = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('iframe');
iframe.src = url;
```

The `url` was already transformed by the save pipe like this:

```
this.safePipe.transform(url, 'resourceUrl');
```